# Android Work Manager: Can I force prune the Completed Jobs?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am uploading photos in my app and want to provide the User with the upload progress.  The way I was going to do this is have a global tag, `UPLOAD_MEDIA_TAG` and use that whenever I am creating a `OneTimeWorkRequest`.  That way I can just observe the `WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusesByTag(UPLOAD_MEDIA_TAG)` LiveData, and whenever a job completes I would show a percent completed. (I.E. Uploading 3/10 photos would show 30%). Then once all 10/10 photos have been uploaded, I would hide the progress bar.  This works great as it easily supports leaving the app, coming back, and you will see the Progress Bar as soon as the app launches right where they left off.

The problem is that once all 10/10 jobs are finished and marked as completed, those jobs will stick around until the WorkManger prunes them. So if the user uploads 5 more photos, the LiveData is returning 15 statuses instead of 5, throwing off the percent calculation.

I noticed there is a method `OneTimeWorkRequest.keepResultsForAtLeast(duration)` but what I would want is something like, `keepResultsForAtMost(duration)` or a `WorkManager.getInstance().forcePrune()` method that would cleanup all the completed jobs from the database.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After submitting an issue with Google, they are saying there will be a function called, `pruneWork` in Alpha03.

Answer (score 0):

As of alpha release, you don't have much control over job pruning since it is managed by `WorkManager`. You can however observe the lifecycle of `WorkManager` to get job status and take necessary action as follows:

```
WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusById(myWork.getId())
    .observe(lifecycleOwner, workStatus -> {
        // Do something with the status
        if (workStatus != null && workStatus.getState().isFinished()){
           // Stop observing data or do other action
        }
    });
```

Note:

Use [WorkManager [1.0.0-alpha03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes) which has several bugs fixed and new features introduced. One you might be interested is:

- Added WorkManager.pruneWork() to remove completed jobs from the internal database

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Doesn't solve my problem, but my question was more of a feature request than anything.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall you shouldn't put feature requests on Stackoverflow since its not the purpose of Stackoverflow . Put it on Google's website.